# Analysis of a case-control study using ordinal logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit, case-control-study

Suppose we have data from a case-control study where for each case having had some disease or event $Y_{binary}$ a control was included that was free of $Y_{binary}$. Due to this study design we cannot estimate the probabilities of $Y_{binary}$ given some $X$, but we can compute valid odds ratios. As such, one can fit a logistic regression model with data from case-control studies and estimate effects of explanatory variables, whereas the intercept term from such a model would not be useful, as it relates to the relative numbers of outcomes of $Y_{binary}=1$ and $Y_{binary}=0$ that are fixed due to the study design.

Suppose that in such a study the event $Y_{binary}$ were (as usually is the case) not strictly binary and we would have further collected additional information allowing us to stratify $Y_{binary}$, say by severity of the event, as an ordinal variable $Y_{ordinal}$. Inclusion in this study, however, and definition as to whether the subject was included as case or control was done ignoring this information, the sampling was only done based on, say, whether $Y$ occurred or not, that is based on $Y_{binary}$. Would it be appropriate to analyze the association of $X$ and $Y$ not using the binary indicator variable on which the study sampling was based on but make use of the additional information by analyzing the ordinal $Y_{ordinal}$ using an ordinal logistic regression model?

With a proportional odds model, for example, we now would have several intercepts $\alpha_{Y≥j}$ depending on the different values $Y_{ordinal}$ could take (or rather depending on the different values that happened to be included in the study), which, as with the binary logistic regression model, could not provide useful estimates, however, the exponentiated $\beta_X$ coefficients from such a model again would provide odds ratios. Would ordinal regression be appropriate and provide valid inference (and maybe increase the power of our study as we could incorporate more information) in case-control studies when sampling was based on some binary form of $Y$ in the same way as simple binary logistic regression?

Comment: An excellent question for which I hope someone has a definitive answer.  For the binary Y case there is a literature showing the validity of ignoring the sampling and using a regular logistic model to get valid odds ratios (even though the intercept is destroyed).  I’ll bet that carries over to ordinal Y (with destroyed intercepts) whether sampling on all of Y or a binary version of it, but I haven’t seen a paper on that.

Comment: Thanks Frank for chiming in, that's what I though too but I am not a statistician. It's reassuring to know that the idea at first glance does not seem too outlandish at least.